# Add an array column to a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, migration

I need help going through the steps to add an array column to a resource using the `rails g migration` command. I have a postgresql database. I need to make an array of strings, and another array of integers. I want it so that in my `schema.rb` file I have...

```
create_table "streams", force: true do |t|
t.array   "ids"     #strings
t.array   "lengths" #integers
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create new migration so `rails g migration change_column_type_of_ids_and_length` . Then edit generated migration file.

1. First try to use `change_column` method. If this works, your data will be preserved. Else, try step 2

   ```
   change_column :streams , :ids , :string , array: true , default: []
   change_column :streams , :lengths, :integer ,array: true , default: []
   ```
2. Here we are removing the column so the data , then creating new one.

   ```
   remove_column :streams, :ids
   remove_column :streams, :lengths
   add_column :streams , :ids , :string ,array: true , default: []
   add_column :streams , :lengths , :integer ,array:  true , default: []
   ```

Comment: How do you create that using the rails g migration command or with a migration file? You can't alter the schema directly

Comment: @Paritosh Piplewar I tried the :string, array: true but i get the following error when migrating `can't quote Array`. 
I can not use the :JSON data type for the field because I am using mysql 5.5

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio the above answer is valid for postgresql.

Comment: @Paritosh Thanks, It worked on mysql 5.5 with the following syntax `change_table :locations do |t|
   t.string :houseimages, array: true
  end`